# Airthmetic calculation PHP

Tags: php

```
$oneGPrice = 41.09;
$oneGPrice = $oneGPrice + ($oneGPrice * 0.28);
$oneGPrice = $oneGPrice + ($oneGPrice * 0.025); // Answer should be 53.9
```

The answer is perfect but I want calculation in one line like this but I am getting wrong answer when I try to do it a line.

```
$oneGPrice = (($oneGPrice + ($oneGPrice * 0.28)) *  0.025) + oneGPrice;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$oneGPrice = ($oneGPrice + ($oneGPrice * 0.28)) +  (($oneGPrice + ($oneGPrice * 0.28)) * 0.025);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is mess up with some brackets and catching values,

```
$oneGPrice = (($oneGPrice + ($oneGPrice * 0.28)) *  0.025) + ($oneGPrice + ($oneGPrice * 0.28));
```

Step1:

`$oneGPrice + ($oneGPrice * 0.28)` This is your second statement which you catched it in `$oneGPrice` meaning now $onePrice ~(similar) `$oneGPrice + ($oneGPrice * 0.28)`

Step2:

In your second statement `$oneGPrice` & `($oneGPrice * 0.025);` two values are there in which `$oneGPrice` ~~(similar) `$oneGPrice + ($oneGPrice * 0.28)` we must replace in both places.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've placed brackets `()` in wrong position, try following code:

```
$oneGPrice = ($oneGPrice + ($oneGPrice * 0.28) *  0.025)) + oneGPrice;
```